# Блокировка удаленного администрирования

Tags: администрирование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, программу блокировки удаленного администрирования, которую можно установить на рабочей станции.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "блокировки удаленного администрирования"?

Answer (score 1):

кхм. достаточно заблокировать стандартные порты программ УА (гугл в помощь), наврядли это выйдет с TeamViewer, ибо он коннектится к внешнему серверу по 443 порту, но на шлюзе можно закрыть данный адрес (что не избавит от подключений его же по локалке, т.к. это он то же умеет, но при этом требуется запущенная пользователем ответная часть программы). Но порты RDP, Radmin, VNC и т.п. Вы закроете.
Сделать это можно с помощью файерволла.

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о Windows, то можно несколько служб (удаленное управление реестром, удаленный рабочий стол, служба терминалов) отключить. Часть из них по умолчанию всегда в рабоче-запускаемом состоянии.

Answer (score 0):

Поставить антивирус и настроить его на блокирование соответствующего класса программ ?)или действительно закрыть файрволом.

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о Windows, (дополняю Зулан)- вырубаем службу "удаленный реестр" и зарубаем шары "с$"  и  "admin$"